# whats the fastest way to write join in linq

Tags: c#, performance, list, linq, dictionary

I have 2 classes user(count-10k),address(count-1million). these are like one to many.

i am trying to map the address for users.

**Using List(takes few minutes):**

```
 List<User> us = usrs.Select(u => new User { id = u.id ,email=u.email,name=u.name,addresses=adrs.Where(a=>a.userid==u.id).ToList()}).ToList();
```

the above works but its very slow

i changed it to use dictionary and its fast.

**Using Dictionary(takes few seconds):**

```
var dusrs = usrs.ToDictionary(usr => usr.id);
        var daddrs = adrs.ToDictionary(adr => Tuple.Create(adr.id,adr.userid));
        foreach (var addr in daddrs)
        {

            var usr = dusrs[addr.Value.userid];
            if (usr.addresses == null)
            {
                usr.addresses = new List<Address>();

            }
            usr.addresses.Add(addr.Value);
        }
```

is there any way i can write better query using list rather than dictionary?

I am just trying to see if i can write better linq using lists

thanks...

vamsee

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a review and thus should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Take a look at [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) method or [join into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Comment: You could use a lookup like `adrs.ToLookUp(k => k.userid)` then extract the address list from the lookup by user id.

Comment: Classes don't contain a count - do you have `List`s of `user` and `address` or some other collection type?

Comment: Can we assume the `user` collection is reduced from the original in some criteria which is why there are 100 addresses per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are keeping users and addresses in `List`s for some reason, you can use a `join` in LINQ which will combine the two `list`s and use a hashed data structure internally to put them together:

```
var us2 = (from u in usrs
          join a in adrs on u.id equals a.userid into aj
          select new User { id = u.id, email = u.email, name = u.name, addresses = aj.Select(a => a).ToList() }).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can convert the addresses into a `Lookup` and use that, but it would probably be best to just keep the addresses in a `Lookup` or create them in a `Lookup` initially if possible:

```
var addressLookup = adrs.ToLookup(a => a.userid);
List<User> us = usrs.Select(u => new User { id = u.id, email=u.email, name=u.name, addresses=addressLookup[u.id].ToList() }).ToList();
```

In my test cases which is faster seems to depend on how many users versus addresses match.

Comment: Deleted my answer since it's identical to yours